# Как это может быть возможно, что resize вектора берет постоянно время на алокацию?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Очень странное поведение которое я встретил в Android NDK

У меня есть луп

```
#include <chrono>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <vector>

while (true)
    {
        const int sz = 2048*2048*3;
        std::vector<unsigned char> v;
        {
            auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            v.resize(sz);
            auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "READFILE 1", "v.resize(%d) time : %lld\n", sz, duration.count());
        }
        {
            auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            v.resize(0);
            auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "READFILE 2", "v.resize(0) time : %lld\n", duration.count());
        }
        {
            auto startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            v.resize(sz);
            auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - startTime);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "READFILE 3", "v.resize(%d) time : %lld\n", sz, duration.count());
        }
    }
```

Вот лог который я получаю

```
34.4171: v.resize(12582912) time : 845977
34.9682: v.resize(0) time : 550995
35.5293: v.resize(12582912) time : 561165
36.6121: v.resize(12582912) time : 530845
37.1612: v.resize(0) time : 548528
37.7183: v.resize(12582912) time : 556559
38.7811: v.resize(12582912) time : 515162
39.3312: v.resize(0) time : 550630
39.8883: v.resize(12582912) time : 556319
40.9711: v.resize(12582912) time : 530739
41.5182: v.resize(0) time : 546654
42.0733: v.resize(12582912) time : 554924
43.1321: v.resize(12582912) time : 511659
43.6802: v.resize(0) time : 547084
44.2373: v.resize(12582912) time : 557001
45.3201: v.resize(12582912) time : 530313
```

Два вопроса:

1. Почему `resize(0)` берет столько времени 550 миллисекунд? Это не должно быть больше чем 0
2. Почему второй `resize(size)` берет опять 550 миллисекунд? `Capacity` осталось же тем же, так почему тогда такое время?

Это два очень не понятных поведения...

Вы можете сами проверить этот код в своей среде, ***но только для Android NDK*** не в VisualStudio, потому что там это работает так как ожидается.

Это выглядит как баг... Но я не нашел ничего в гугле об этом

или я что то делаю не правильно?

**EDIT**

Я обратил внимание, что если пойти в метод `resize()` то, приходим в такой метод

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
void
__vector_base<_Tp, _Allocator>::__destruct_at_end(pointer __new_last) _NOEXCEPT
{
    pointer __soon_to_be_end = __end_;
    while (__new_last != __soon_to_be_end)
        __alloc_traits::destroy(__alloc(), _VSTD::__to_raw_pointer(--__soon_to_be_end));
    __end_ = __new_last;
}
```

А это говорит о том, что есть цикл по каждому элементу который попал в `resize` и это логично, что вызывается `destroy` для каждого элемента, но только если это не тривиальный обьект. А если это int (например), то у него даже нет дестрактора...

Что это тогда? Баг компиляции?

Comment: Это случаем не еще один вопрос про измерение производительности кода в отладочной сборке7

Comment: Найти  такое количество байтов в памяти с инициализацией данных, не так уж легко. При этом освобождается старая память, что тоже не так уж быстро,   resize(0) только и делает, что освобождает память, но так как память была распределена раз, после этого для всех  resize наверняка время уходит только на освобождение(ИМХО)

Comment: [vector/resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize), Complexity
Linear in the difference between the current size and count. Additional complexity possible due to reallocation if capacity is less than count

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `resize` ни при каких обстоятельствах не уменьшает емкость вектора, так что никакого освобождения памяти `resize(0)` тут не происходит, как и новой аллокации при втором `resize(sz);`

Comment: @VTT нет в релизе то же время. Я добавил в вопрос правку.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Я добавил в вопрос правку.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Я добавил в вопрос правку.